# Xcode can't run iPad Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a `Main_iPhone.storyboard` which works great. Now I build a `Main_iPad.storyboard`. Now when I want to test the iPad App with the iPad Simulator. The Simulator Displays me the `Main_iPhone.storyboard` and not the `iPad Storyboard`. It's a Universal App but it does not work. The Main Interface for the iPad is the `Main_iPad.storyboard`. So I don't know where the mistake is :(

Anyone an idea?

Update:
i got it... my if/elseif doesn't work anymore so it picked always the `Main_iPhone` in the `AppDelegate`...

Comment: What is the project setting for "Main Storyboard" under iPad Deployment Info? You say that the "Main Interface for the iPad is `Main_iPad.storyboard` but you don't specify if you've set it specifically in the project settings.

Comment: In the Project under Deployment Info and then under iPad the Main Interface is Main_iPad

Comment: Try cleaning your project (cmd+shift+k) and resetting your iOS Simulator. If those didn't work, you might wanna check if your storyboard is being included in the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the app iPhone only when you created the project, and then added the storyboard for iPad, you need click on the root (blue icon) in the Project Navigator, then under General -> Deployment Info, make sure Devices is set to Universal. You will also see there 2 buttons iPhone and iPad. Select iPad and set main interface to Main_iPad. This should work.

Comment: it was from the beginning to universial... and on the Deveopment Info -> iPad side the Main Interface is Main_iPad